# Ранний возврат из функции рекурсивным способом

Tags: php, рекурсия, рефакторинг

В последнее время, чтобы избежать чрезмерно вложенных `If` я пользуюсь принципом раннего возврата. Однако возникают ситуации, когда этот принцип может "засорить" код. Например, сегодня нужно вернуть `json` с результатами, поэтому можно делать так:

```
public function canSendSms( ) {
        $shopId = $this->request->post['shop_id'];
        $dateEnd = $this->request->post['dateEnd'];
        $orderId = $this->request->post['order_id'];

        if ( ! $shopId || !$dateEnd || !$orderId ) {
            $result["error"][] = "Неверные данные";
            header("Content-type: application/json");
            return json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        }

        // Собираем оставшиеся данные
        $this->load->model('sale/order');
        $order_info = $this->model_sale_order->getOrder($orderId);
        if ( !$order_info ) {
            $result["error"][] = "Не получилось найти заказ под номером " . $orderId;
            header("Content-type: application/json");
            return json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        }

        // финальный код

        $result["success"][] = "Сообщение можно отправить";
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        return json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
```

Как видно из примера - тут 3 раза повторяются 2 строки вывода

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
return json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Если метод небольшой, и изменений не планируется, то проблем нет. Но что если таких проверок будет 10, а формат вывода поменяется с `json` на какой-нибудь другой? Ну да, придется тупо изменить вывод в этих 10 проверках.

В связи с этим, я начал использовать рекурсию, в итоге финальный возврат теперь всегда в подобных случаях осуществляется в начале метода. Выглядит это таким образом

```
public function canSendSms( $result = NULL ) {
        if ( $result ) {
            header("Content-type: application/json");
            echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            return;
        }

        $shopId = $this->request->post['shop_id'];
        $dateEnd = $this->request->post['dateEnd'];
        $orderId = $this->request->post['order_id'];

        if ( ! $shopId || !$dateEnd || !$orderId ) {
            $result["error"][] = "Неверные данные";
            return $this->canSendSms( $result );
        }

        // Собираем оставшиеся данные
        $this->load->model('sale/order');
        $order_info = $this->model_sale_order->getOrder($orderId);
        if ( !$order_info ) {
            $result["error"][] = "Не получилось найти заказ под номером " . $orderId;
            return $this->canSendSms( $result );
        }

        // какой-то код

        $result["success"][] = "Сообщение можно отправить";
        return $this->canSendSms( $result );
    }
```

**Вопрос, насколько это правильно, насколько понимаемо и встречается ли подобное в вашей практике?**

Comment: Очень мутно в итоге - зачем рекурсия? У вас в итоге есть алгоритм проверки заказа и отсылка - разделите это в две разных функции - пусть функция с проверкой называется checkOrder, функция отсылки - sendSms, вызываемая в конце функции checkOrder через return $this->sendSms($result), а еще лучше в корневом коде где будет решаться что делать с результатом проверки. Поместите отсылку в отдельную функцию и не плодите муть дальше.

Comment: предоставьте мне решать что и где, а так же как отвечать. Я ответил по сути - у вас в коде получается мешанина, в одной и той же функции два функционала, пусть даже и с "добрыми" намерениями. Поддерживать такой код после будет сложно.

Comment: А зачем вы в вашей функции canSendSms пишите echo если она должна возвращать результат, а не выводить его?

Comment: @Bykuznec эта функция обрабатывает ajax запрос. Если вернуть json через return, то js ничего не получит. Поэтому echo

Comment: $canSendSms = canSendSms($params); echo $canSendSms; - Вот вам и json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас функция делает две разные задачи. Это как если ложкой мешать чай, а потом перелистывать страницы книги ей же. Согласитесь - странно.

Вам нужна какая-то другая функция, которую вы будете вызывать из этой. Тогда  таких вопросов не будет. Рекурсия нужна не для того и выглядит не так.

Если ещё одну функцию сделать мешают причины какие-то, то можно использовать исключения (хуже) или одноразовый цикл (лучше):

```
public function canSendSms($result = [])
{
    do {
        $shopId = $this->request->post['shop_id'];
        $dateEnd = $this->request->post['dateEnd'];
        $orderId = $this->request->post['order_id'];

        if (!$shopId || !$dateEnd || !$orderId) {
            $result["error"][] = "Неверные данные";
            break;
        }

        // Собираем оставшиеся данные
        $this->load->model('sale/order');
        $order_info = $this->model_sale_order->getOrder($orderId);
        if (!$order_info) {
            $result["error"][] = "Не получилось найти заказ под номером $orderId";
            break;
        }

        $result["success"][] = "Сообщение можно отправить";
    } while (false);

    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

В остальном вам очень хорошо [следует подумать над структурой программы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). Например, как будет выглядеть юнит-тест для этой функции, если она сразу пишет данные с заголовками?..

Comment: По сути первоначальная задача была избежать дополнительной вложенности операторов и чтобы при этом не нужно было дублировать финальный вывод, поэтому я использовал `return` так же, как вы используете в примере `break`, имея одиночный цикл.  Но про юнит-тесты и на тему побочных эффектов не подумал. спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вы как-то странно ограниченны одной функцией. Вам надо понять что делает та или иная функция и разбить её на составляющие. Тут например у Вас есть следующие атомы:

1. Проверка входных параметров
2. Проверка валидности данных
3. Отправка ответа.

Если Вы дополнительно реализуете их отдельными функциями, всё станет проще:

1. ValidateParams params - на вход, true если всё хорошо, текст/код ошибки - если всё плохо
2. ValidateData - аналогично
3. Validate - функция которая последовательно применяет первые две
4. SendResponce - Собственно формирование ответа

и тогда у вас получится что то типа

```
SendSms(){
res = Validate(...)
if(res==true){
    res = "Успешно"
}
SendResponce(res);
}
```

Comment: По сути в моем вопросе и представлена функция `Validate`, в которой проводится проверка валидности данных. Просто неудачно обозначил название изначально. Вопрос был в другом

Comment: Тогда не понятно в чём вопрос. Использовать рекурсию для того, чтобы одна и та же функция возвращала логически разный результат? Это попахивает извращением. И уязвимостью - я могу вызвать эту функцию с параметром и она ничего не проверит, а отдаст параметр в каком-то формате

Comment: суть вопрос изложил в комментариях к ответу выше. Про уязвимость это понятно, но эта функция доступна только в административной панели

Comment: Вы так рассуждаете, пока у Вас Вы один разработчик кода. Это уязвимость с точки зрения написания кода. Ну не говоря уже что можно случайно что-то сделать даже из админской панели.